# HSM KW command to validate ARQC

Tags: encoding, cryptography, hex, emv, hsm

I am trying to send `KW` command to Thales HSM, the description for one of the field data is:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
| PAN/PAN Sequence No | 8B | this field will be fixed at 8 bytes |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Let say my data is `6542000000193400`.

Does that means I have to convert it from hex to char?

Comment: Does that means I ve to convert it from hex to char?

Comment: It is a value of 8 Bytes, i.e. in your case should be 0x65 0x42 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x19 0x34 0x00

Comment: Sometimes this format is called BCD (Binary Coded Decimal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would mean that you would need to decode your hexadecimals to `char` before inserting it into the command data.

You've written your data in hexadecimals. So *if* your data really is in hexadecimals inside your application then you need to hex decode to bytes. Bytes are represented by the `char` or `unsigned char` in the C/C++ language.

Note that bytes are often represented to you (by e.g. debuggers) in hexadecimals. So you should be careful not to decode bytes that are not actually hexadecimals. Check the origin and size of the hex before you start.

Comment: thanks you, btw since null value terminate a string, how can i possibly sent null data to HSM when i m using C codes?

Comment: PKCS#11 calls in general include a parameter specifying the length. So the char values are seen as bytes and nul values are send as is any other value.

Comment: any suggestion on where should I start with this PKCS#11? any good reading material?

Comment: I generally just read the standards. They are often better than any introductory work. In this case try [here (EMC.com)](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/pkcs-11-cryptographic-token-interface-standard.htm). The newest 2.40 version is at OASIS, but you probably won't find many implementations in the wild yet.